# why script tag append is not working wheni try to append script tag inside the vf page?

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page >
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function () {              
        $('.container').append("<script>console.log('Something is running');</script>");

     });
    </script>
    <div class="container"></div>
</apex:page>


      //For some reason i need this to be appended
       // Its not allowing me to save. 

    //Error: The element type "apex:page" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:page>".
```

Comment: It looks at a element named with class as test where it appends it. Right now your page doesn't has any.

Comment: my mistake.. its there actually ..forgot to include. but its not allowing me to save

Comment: Is your opening tag really `<apex;page>`? It's supposed to be a colon (`:`) not a semicolon (`;`).

Comment: I have updated the minimum code and try to save buut got the same error.

Comment: Your question would more likely be closed, kindly learn the basics first instead of copy pasting code. There are many related questions in [stackoverflow](http://bfy.tw/G4ds) on how to append script tag with JavaScript.

Comment: Mmm....Thanks for the advise.  Some time it happens .:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add one more "/" in the end script tag. because it is a delimiter.

Comment: Its allowed me to save. but  <\/script> actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

@Sam had it right - you're missing a second `\`. The first one is compiled as an escape character. Apex expects something like, `\n` or `\t`. The trick is, when you need to use an escape character, you have to escape it. It looks like `\\`, but will output `\`.

```
<apex:page>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.someDiv').append("<script>console.log('say something');<//script>");    
        });
    </script>
    <div class="someDiv">

    </div>
</apex:page>
```